# Web-based .resx file editor?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, localization, internationalization

I'm working on a SharePoint site, and the site eventually needs to be localized to many different languages. We can use resource files, but we'd like for the translators to be able to update those files while the site is live, without requiring developer assistance to recompile, redeploy, etc.

To me, I think the easiest way to do this would be to provide a web application to edit the .resx files as they sit in the App_GlobalResources directory. Does anyone know of some sort of a web-based .resx editor like that? I found one [from LavaBlast](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/02/RESX-file-Web-Editor.aspx), but it displays the values for all languages at once. With the number of languages we plan on having, I think that would eventually get unwieldy.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: LavaBlast's solution is awesome :) Did you end up enhancing it?

Comment: It's been so long that I don't remember. I think we found a way to accomplish what we were looking for without going this route, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I used the one you found: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/02/RESX-file-Web-Editor.aspx  It took a couple of hours but it works a treat.  I think that having the multiple languages editable at the same time is very helpful to avoid getting your resx files out of sync, and to see blank entries easily.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution, but [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) contains a full lanaguage file editor, you might be able to extract the logic from it for your own use.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a tool called the Enterprise Localization Toolkit you might look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479334.aspx

It has been ages since I played with it, but it should fit at least some of your requirements. It is easy enough for a non-techie to use. You do not edit RESX directly, however, so it might not be exactly what you need. You gen them instead and then deploy.